# Jest setup beforeAll runing multiple times but Its called in setupFilesAfterEnv

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, automated-tests, ts-jest

I'm trying to configure the global with supertest and Jest.
I'm using Typescript and express.

My jest-setup.js:

```js
import supertest from 'supertest';
import app from '../src/config/app';
import start from '../src/server';

beforeAll(async () => {
  console.log(':::::::::::::STARTING TEST SERVER:::::::::::::');
  await start();
  global.testRequest = supertest(app);
});
```

My jest.config.ts inside tests folder:

```js
const { resolve } = require('path');

const root = resolve(__dirname, '..');
const rootConfig = require(`${root}/jest.config.js`);

module.exports = {
  ...rootConfig,
  rootDir: root,
  displayName: 'TESTS::',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/test/jest-setup.ts'],
  testMatch: ['<rootDir>/test/**/*.test.ts'],
  restoreMocks: true,
  clearMocks: true,
  resetMocks: true,
};
```

my jest.config.js in root folder (I'v done this way to separate unit test so it doesn't start server'):

```js
const { resolve } = require('path');

const root = resolve(__dirname);

module.exports = {
  rootDir: root,
  displayName: 'TESTS::',
  testMatch: ['<rootDir>/src/**/*.test.ts'],
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  clearMocks: true,
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    '<rootDir>/src/modules/**/*.ts',
    '!<rootDir>/src/modules/**/*.test.ts',
  ],
  coverageReporters: ['text-summary', 'lcov'],
  coverageDirectory: 'coverage',
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '@src/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
    '@test/(.*)': '<rootDir>/test/$1',
  },
};
```

the script to run integration tests:

**"test": "NODE_ENV=test jest --projects ./test --forceExit --runInBand"**

But jest is starting the server before each test. The first test passes and the next ones breaks trying to start server again. Follows a piece of the log:

```
> NODE_ENV=test jest --projects ./test --forceExit --runInBand

 PASS   TESTS::  test/e2e/farm/insert-one.test.ts
  ● Console

    console.log
      :::::::::::::STARTING TEST SERVER:::::::::::::

      at Object.<anonymous> (test/jest-setup.ts:6:11)

 FAIL   TESTS::  test/e2e/user/login.test.ts
  ● Console

    console.log
      :::::::::::::STARTING TEST SERVER:::::::::::::

      at Object.<anonymous> (test/jest-setup.ts:6:11)

  ● User.loginController › should login and return 200

    listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000

      21 |     }
      22 | 
    > 23 |     app.listen(env.port, () => logger.info(`Server running ${env.port}`));
         |         ^
      24 |   } catch (err) {
      25 |     logger.error(err);
      26 |   }

      at Function.listen (node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
      at Object.<anonymous>.exports.default (src/server.ts:23:9)
      at Object.<anonymous> (test/jest-setup.ts:7:3)
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Do not start a server in tests, Supertest does this for you.

Comment: Thank you very much! You'r rigth! Please answer this quastion so I can upvote you!